How many iPhone backup copies are kept on iCloud?
(I see this question has been asked before, but long ago).
I had a scare with my iPhone (iOS 17.4.1, iPhone 11) that seems resolved -- I thought I could have gotten a virus (the probability now seems vanishingly small).  I don't need to restore from an iCloud backup, but I looked to check to see how one does that, just so I know.  I went to settings and then to iCloud and then to the backup page.  I only see one backup, and that was from this morning, after the incident occurred.  So if something had happened, I would have no way to restore to a backup previous to the event.
So if something were to require a restore from a backup, do I need to do so very quickly?  I had thought that perhaps the last 3 to 5 backups might be stored on iCloud.  Is there a way to increase the number -- so that one has access to a number of backups from the last several days?  Am I simply not seeing the multiple backups that are there?  If so, how would I?

Not an answer to your specific question (I just don't know...) but I always have at least two reasonably current backups of my iPhone: iCloud and locally on my Mac. Yeah it's not the most convienent to do a manual backup weekly or monthly, but it has saved my bacon at least a couple of times.

I can't point to an Apple document saying so, but I've had iCloud Backup turned on since my iP12Pro, and I looked today and the only date listed is yesterday.  That being said, the verbiage on the iCloud dialog in System Settings (from the Mac) definitely implies there can be more than one.  It's not something I'd ever trust anyway, it's turned on because it's only 99c/month, not because I expect it to be there.  It's iCloud, after all.  The backup to the Mac is what I count on.

Really, IMO the correct answer is that the phone shouldn't ever be authoritative, which is what I practice.
